# How do I create a .txt file from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export

I have a dataframe in my jupyter notebook, which follows the below format for ~1500 rows:

```
BUSINESS    CUSTOMER_ID     RISK_RATING
PVB          1000033280         HR
SLA          1000064680         LR
```

I want to output this df as a .txt file, similar to how I have used `df.to_csv`.

I have tried this code:

`np.savetxt(r'Y:\FILEPATH\df.txt', df.values, fmt='%d', delimiter='\t')`

But I am currently getting this error message:

`TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%d   %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d')`

I also want to make sure the column headers (`"BUSINESS", "CUSTOMER_ID" & "RISK_RATING"`) are included in the .txt file.

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use df.to_csv and just give a .txt name to your file. See below:

```
df.to_csv('filename.txt')
```